# Can I pass an SSH Tunnel credentials into a postgresql PgAdmin Connection string?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am following [this](https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/en/replicating-a-postgresql-database-in-a-windows-workstation/) guide for replication across postgresql tables. It is fairly straight forward and so far I have no issues. However, this string is will be a hurdle:

```
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION subscri_partners CONNECTION ‘dbname = postgres host = 195.83.124.222 user = rep password = Password port = 5433’ PUBLICATION publi_partners;
```

I have my postgresql db in a docker container which I access through SSH forwarding. I do have PGAdmin successfully connecting to it because PGAdmin has a section to fill in the information to SSH tunnel. However, I can not find any documents on if the connection string supports ssh port forwarding. I see quite a few connections asking this, and answers range from using a Putty SSH tunnel to they plan on implementing this. However, since an ssh tunnel can be put in the config, I would assume it can not be put in this string. Is this true?